# Macro doesn't work one only one of 10 computers

Tags: excel, vba

My colleague is having issues with little macro I made that just drops down formulas by clicking a button. The macro works on every other computer but hers.

When crunching line:

```
j = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Workbooks("Backlog_Cal").Worksheets("Menu").Range("I:I")) - 1
```

It gives subscription out of range error as if it would contain spelling error in name.

When I made just a test macro

```
dim j as long
j = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("I:I"))
MsgBox j
```

where sheet menu was active it worked.

I'm afraid of this messing up my other macros that I make for someone in future.

Comment: Try to add extension to the workbook name, for example "Backlog_Cal.xlsx"

Comment: As @Teamothy suggested, it can happen on computers having the Folder setting "Hide extensions for known file types" unchecked. Default for it is checked...

Comment: @braX: Probably, yes. But the guy who asked doesn't say anything...

Comment: @Teamothy May I ask how you add extension in the workbooks("Backlog_Cal.xlsx")? Because when I add it simply Workbooks("Backlog_Cal.xlsx").activate, it its Subscription out of range error due that not being the file name. I googled and someone had a bit similar problem with that and he used debug.print but I can't put the sintax together in this case

Comment: Thank you @FaneDuru, colleague is only one using WIN7 with extensions are shown. Now I will have to find a way of working with this. But big thanks

Comment: @MarekKollmann but why You want to activate? Just put that whole name in CountA function. Also see the topic at the top of your post.

Comment: But doing what @Teamothy suggested will make the code working in both/all situations... Use the full workbook name (extension included: .xlsx, xlsm, .xls etc.). Maybe your workbook is not a .xlsx type, like Teamothy suggested...